# Copying SQL Server query results into an Access 2010 table

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access-2010

Monthly, I need to get "new" data from our SQL Server business application into an Access 2010 database that contains all our "Management Reports".  The Access database has a "staging table" that is to contain the raw data on which the reports are based.

I have no Access experience, but I suggested that we:

1. Write a query (stored proc?) on our SQL Server that returns the required raw data (...this bit was easy.)
2. At the end of each month, call the SQL Server stored proc from within Access 2010 (...click a button?)
3. Save the results of the stored proc into the staging table within Access.

But I'm finding it harder than I expected.  I think I can get something ugly working using ADODB in a code-behind, looping through rows in a recordset one by one, and then setting column values one by one.  But there must be a better way  :)

- How should I go about getting SQL Server data from Access 2010?  (ADODB? DAO? QueryDesigner? other?)
- Is there a "Insert Recordset Into Table" (or similar) mechanism that I can leverage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link the relevant sql server table or view to MS Access. Run a query against the linked table using MS Access syntax and update the staging table.

It is also possible to update an MS Access table using a connection string for SQL Server in-line in your query.

```
SELECT *
INTO   newtable
FROM   [odbc;filedsn=Z:\DSN\test.dsn].table1
```

Working from the SQL Server end, you can use MS Access as a linked server or run a query and update from there.

```
INSERT INTO
OPENDATASOURCE(
   'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Data Source=z:\docs\test.accdb')...[table1] 
   ( atext )
SELECT atext FROM table1 WHERE id=2
```

Comment: "Link the relevant sql server table or view":  my SQL Server data is a long query that takes date-range input parameters. Can I still use this mechanism?  Or does it only work on a single table or view.

Comment: "Working from the SQL Server end": nice elegant solution... though in my scenario we would like to use an Access DB that could live in the desktop of a local PC.  i.e. Not impossible to do from the SQL Server end, but a pull-via-Access would be our ideal solution.

Comment: In that case, either create a table in sql server from the long query or run the long query in MS Access.

Comment: Thanks @Remou, very helpful - FYI we've gone with your first option: I've changed my stored proc to a view and can now pull that SQL Server data into Access.