# Return stored procedure data to ms access table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures

I'm calling a stored procedure in SQL Server that includes parameters and returns a dataset.

I need to find a good way of importing this data into an Access table.  Is it possible to do it in one go or can I attach the recordset to a query and the paste the records into a table in a second step.  I'd appreciate any pointers.

```
Private Sub GetOpex()
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

    cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=dbaseIntegrated Security=SSPI;"

    cnn.Open
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = cnn.Execute("ProceName, 9, 2014, 22")

    # Insert to an Access Table


    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cnn.Close
    Set cnn = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Comment: Just cycle through the ADODB rows to retrieve the data and use DAO to insert it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying SQL Server query results into an Access 2010 table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366590/copying-sql-server-query-results-into-an-access-2010-table)

Comment: Ron - I didn't want to step through the rows as it would take too long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a Pass-through query and call a T-SQL `EXECUTE` to the procedure:

```
EXEC ProceName, 9, 2014, 22
```

Save it (e.g. as ExecSP), than you can run a `SELECT INTO` query in Access:

```
SELECT * INTO YOUR_NEW_TABLE
FROM ExecSP
```

Comment: Thanks Andrea, this is just what I was looking for.  Didn't realize pass through queries could be parametrized.